# iPhone duplicate/copy a viewcontroller entirely

Tags: iphone, copy, duplicates, viewcontroller

I have a view controller with user content like text/images/location data and i would like to duplicate the viewController and present it modally (presentModalViewController) when the user taps the edit button. The reason for doing this is because i want it to be clear that the user is entering the edit mode by using the transition/animation that comes with a modally presented controller.

Does anybody knows how to duplicate an entire viewController + its view? i don't want the overhead of reallocating the entire viewController. I tried a couple of things, but i haven't had any luck.

Any help/information would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a little impractical. You could make an image of the current screen contents, present that using whatever animation you like on top of everything, and then remove it?

Or make other changes to your view (rearrangement of views, appearance of other controls, changes of colour) in your viewController's `setEditing:animated:` method.

Comment: Making an image is a bit too hacky for me.. What about duplicating the view only? Is that possible?

Comment: You could create a blank view controller and set its `view` property to the current controller's `view`, then present it modally? However you would then want to get rid of it and do your editing in the "real" view controller because none of the internal state would be present.

Comment: Just tried it, as soon as i present it modally, the original view disappears which doesn't look very nice. Their's no way to actually copy the view or controller?

Comment: You can implement NSCopying on your viewcontroller and all objects therein, but I don't think it would be worth the effort...